# How to print arguments names of printf from LLVM-IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

Can any one please help me in finding the actual argument names of `printf()` call from **LLVM-IR**.

For example : I am having `printf("%d,%d,x,y);` statement in program.

I am writing **LLVM** pass for finding actual argument names (x and y in above example).

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is by using `CallExpr` to identify printf calls.
You would use `getArgs()` instead of `getArg(0)` and use an iterator to parse through the arguments.

```
const Expr* expr = CE->getArg(0); //CE is the CallExpr for printf
if (const ImplicitCaseExpr* ICE = 
             llvm::dyn_cast<ImplicitCastExpr>(expr)) {
     const Expr* DRE_VAR = ICE->getSubExpr();
     //now, cast and parse the AST
}
```

**EDIT:** Looking at this a couple of months later, I can tell you that the only way to do this would be for you to do the placeholder mapping.